# How to add custom rest APi function in Sylius?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, sylius

I'm new at Sylius I would like to extend the Sylius rest api to add some actions like getting a list of products by taxon/variant/option ...
is there any documentation that helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what it worths, they are reviewing the whole documentation, for the close v1.0 alpha.

You could have a look here https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/5275

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question.